# Why is there a Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT when my alert tries to pop up?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am not too good with debugging and figuring out errors. So my app basically has a notification which when the action on the notification that says "Call" is pressed, a alert pops up and it calls the number that you had originally put in the UITextField when scheduling the notification. When the action brings me into the app for some reason I don't even get an alert and a `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT` error pops up. Any help would be awesome:) Thanks. Here is my  code where the problem is likely coming from:

In my ViewController subclass:

```
func showAlert(title: String, message : String, buttonTitle1: String, buttonTitle2: String,window: UIWindow){

    // create the alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // add the actions (buttons)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle1, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(self.phoneNumber.text)") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        }
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle2, style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))    

    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Main Stuff
var window: UIWindow?
```

And a ViewController extension:

```
extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        if response.actionIdentifier == "call" {
            self.showAlert(title: "Enter Call", message: "Are you sure?", buttonTitle1: "Go", buttonTitle2: "Cancel", window: self.window!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and delete code not associated with your issue. And please point out the exact line causing the error.

Comment: @rmaddy just updated the code

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint?  Look for a blue flag in the margin.

Answer (score 0):

To turn off unexpected breakpoints, you can go to the "Breakpoint Navigator".

Along the left side of your Xcode window, you'll see the icon that looks like a trapezoid (it's the red circle in the top left of this screenshot):

[image: Breakpoint Navigator]

And while I simply have one breakpoint currently set in my screenshot, you might have more breakpoints set in your project (by accident). If you toggle the blue flag, the breakpoint will be disabled.  And you can drag and pull that flag away from the column and the breakpoint will be deleted.

You can also hold down the control key while clicking on the flag and you'll see a pop-up menu that allows you to do the same thing.

Lastly, there's a "Deactivate Breakpoints" menu option in Xcode's "Debug" menu, where you can toggle the menu between "Deactivate" and "Activate".

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting a crash because you are initiating UI activities outside of the main thread. Try wrapping your UIAlert call in a DispatchQueue like this:

```
func showAlert(title: String, message : String, buttonTitle1: String, buttonTitle2: String,window: UIWindow){

   DispatchQueue.main.async {

    // create the alert
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // add the actions (buttons)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle1, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(self.phoneNumber.text)") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        }
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle2, style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))    

    // show the alert
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried using it but the error is still there:(